# HazelcastClient ringbuffer gives UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: hazelcast

Using

```
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
Ringbuffer<String> mybuffer = client.getRingbuffer("rb");
```

and connecting as a client to a multicast joiner is giving error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.HazelcastClientProxy.getRingbuffer(HazelcastClientProxy.java:73)
```

but using another hazelcast instance works fine:

```
HazelcastInstance client = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
Ringbuffer<String> mybuffer = client.getRingbuffer("rb");
```

Thing is, it may be preferable to connect as a client to the already existing multicast instance rather than starting another instance. Is this by design, or what am I doing wrong?

THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client-Side implementation of RingBuffer is missing in 3.5 and 3.5.1 versions. It's available in 3.5.2+ though.